# No Accuracy in my tensorflow network

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm new in tensorflow and machine learning but I'm trying to build this network with tensorflow but there is no accuracy and loss not changed !

**Here is the network**

**Init All Variables**

```
import tensorflow as tf, data # get custom dataset

training_dir = 'Datasets/att_faces/Training'
testing_dir = 'Datasets/att_faces/Testing'


filterSize1 = 5
numFilters1 = 64
maxPooling1 = 2

filterSize2 = 5
numFilters2 = 32
maxPooling2 = 2

filterSize3 = 5
numFilters3 = 16
maxPooling3 = 2


fullyConn1 = 1024
fullyConn2 = 256

dropout = 0.75

imageSize = 92*112
imageWidth = 92
imageHeight = 112

NClasses = 40
BatchSize = 10

NEpochs = 50
learningRate = 0.001

NChannels = 1

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, imageSize])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, NClasses])
keepRatio = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

X, Y= data.LoadTrainingData(training_dir, (imageWidth, imageHeight))
data.TrainingData = X
data.TrainingLables = Y

XT, YT, NamesT, Classes, Paths = data.LoadTestingData(testing_dir, (imageWidth, imageHeight))
data.TestingData = XT
data.TestingLables = YT
print (len(X), len(Y), len(XT), len(YT), len(NamesT), len(Paths))
```

**New weights and biases**

```
def newWeight(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=shape, stddev=0.05))
    #return tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=shape))

def newBiases(length):
    return tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.05, shape=[length]))
    #return tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([length]))
```

**Conv2d and maxpooling**

```
def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, filter=W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME")

def maxpool2d(layer, filterSize):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(value=layer, ksize=[1, filterSize, filterSize, 1], strides=[1, filterSize, filterSize, 1], padding="SAME")
```

**Define new convolution layer**

```
def newConvLayer(input, numInputChannels, filterSize, numFilters, activation='relu', usePooling=True, poolingFilter = 3):

    shape = [filterSize, filterSize, numInputChannels, numFilters]

    Weights = newWeight(shape=shape)

    Biases = newBiases(length=numFilters)

    layer = conv2d(input, Weights)

    layer = tf.nn.bias_add(layer, Biases)

    if(activation=='relu'):
        layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)
    else:
        layer = tf.nn.tanh(layer)

    if usePooling:
        layer = maxpool2d(layer, poolingFilter)

    return layer
```

**Reshape image to feed it to hidden layer**

```
def flattenLayer(input):
    layerShape = input.get_shape() # [num_images, height, width, num_channels]

    num_features =  layerShape[1:4].num_elements()

    Layer = tf.reshape(input, [-1, num_features])

    print "Flatten Layer: " + str(num_features)

    return Layer, num_features
```

**Define fully connected layer**

```
def newFCLayer(input, numInput, numOutput, isOut = False, activation='tanh', dropout=0.75):

    Weights = newWeight(shape=[numInput, numOutput])
    Biases = newBiases(length=numOutput)

    layer = tf.matmul(input, Weights)
    layer = tf.nn.bias_add(layer, Biases)

    if(isOut):
        return layer

    if activation=='tanh':
        layer = tf.nn.tanh(layer)
    else:
        layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)

    layer = tf.nn.dropout(layer, dropout)

    return layer
```

**Building the network**

```
def CNN(input, keepratio):
    network = tf.reshape(input, [-1, imageWidth, imageHeight, NChannels])

    network = newConvLayer(input=network, numInputChannels=NChannels, filterSize=filterSize1,
                        numFilters=numFilters1,
                            poolingFilter=maxPooling1)

    network = newConvLayer(input=network, numInputChannels=numFilters1,
                        filterSize=filterSize2, numFilters=numFilters2,
                            poolingFilter=maxPooling2)

   # network = newConvLayer(input=network, numInputChannels=numFilters2,
    #                    filterSize=filterSize3, numFilters=numFilters3,
     #                       poolingFilter=maxPooling3)


    network, NumFeatures = flattenLayer(network)
    network = newFCLayer(network, NumFeatures, fullyConn1, activation='relu', dropout=keepratio)
    #network = newFCLayer(network, fullyConn1, fullyConn2, activation='tanh', dropout=keepratio)
    network = newFCLayer(network, fullyConn1, NClasses, isOut=True)

    return network
```

**Main**

```
def main():
    Prediction = CNN(x, keepRatio)

    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=Prediction, labels=y))

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learningRate).minimize(cost)
    correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    init2 = tf.local_variables_initializer()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        sess.run(init2)
        rang = int(len(X) / BatchSize)
        if len(X) % BatchSize != 0:
            rang += 1

        for epoch in range(NEpochs):
            for i in range(rang):
                epochX, epochY = data.nextBatch(BatchSize)

                epochX = epochX.reshape(BatchSize, imageSize)

                feeds = {x: epochX, y:epochY, keepRatio: 0.75}

                sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feeds)

                loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x:epochX, y:epochY, keepRatio:1.})

                print("Epoch: %01d/%01d loss: %.4f Acc: %.4f" %(epoch, NEpochs, loss, acc))

            print "Epoch " + str(epoch) + " Finished !"
```

**Output**

```
(360, 360, 40, 40, 40, 40)
Flatten Layer: 20608

Epoch: 0/50 loss: 3.7418 Acc: 0.9000
Epoch: 0/50 loss: 4.3752 Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 0/50 loss: 4.5419 Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 0/50 loss: 2.3754 Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 0/50 loss: 2.7341 Acc: 0.0000

Epoch: 16/50 loss: 3.7056 Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 16/50 loss: 3.7036 Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 16/50 loss: 3.7028 Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 16/50 loss: 3.7009 Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 16/50 loss: 3.7084 Acc: 0.0000

Epoch: 29/50 loss: 3.6965 Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 29/50 loss: 3.6930 Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 29/50 loss: 3.6932 Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 29/50 loss: 3.6973 Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 29/50 loss: 3.6910 Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 29/50 loss: 3.6905 Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 29/50 loss: 3.6862 Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 29/50 loss: 3.6953 Acc: 0.0000

Epoch: 34/50 loss: 3.6851 Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 34/50 loss: 3.6827 Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 34/50 loss: 3.6839 Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 34/50 loss: 3.6904 Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 34/50 loss: 3.7003 Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 34/50 loss: 3.6942 Acc: 0.0000
Epoch: 34/50 loss: 3.6979 Acc: 0.0000
```

**Sorry about this long code** but I'm trying on it for three days and still no change! 
**Thanks for helping :)**

Comment: don't expect that someone will go through your complete code. just provide the code which you think is relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are some points:

1) shuffle your data to prevent that each batch contain only one class,

2) increase your batch size, at least as same as classes number,

3) increase your model capacity(more layers, smaller filter sizes),

4) make sure, your labels are in one-hot vector format,

5) remove two-step of initializing, one of them is enough.

6) it seems you use "The ORL Database of Faces" which contains only 400 samples, it's very small for deep learning task, try to have data augmentation(create artificially images like original one, such as rotating, flipping, blur, add noise, zoom in, zoom out,...)